# Should I be worried about my SSD deteriorating from file transfers?

Tags: windows-7, performance, ssd, trim

I'm a GIS analyst so I deal with huge imagery datasets daily (80GB+).  Processing from our server is extremely slow so I copy files to my local drive before processing.  I have both an SSD and an HDD on this system where I can store the data temporarily.

Should I be concerned with my SSD performance deteriorating if I continually copy over large datasets for processing (in which case I should use the HDD for temp file storage)?

Comment: Short answer: yes Additional info: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/10/maximizing-the-lifetime-of-your-ssd/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is excessive for a non-enterprise SSD.  To put this in comparison, for Intel consumer SSDs (which are commonly considered by far the best drives on the market in terms of reliability rather than raw benchmark numbers), Intel guarantees that they'll do 20GB of writes per day for the entire warranty period without exhausting the drive.  You're doing significantly more than that, and if it's not an Intel drive there's no guarantee that it's as resilient, so while this isn't a short-term concern I might be concerned about the longevity of this.

Enterprise SSDs are generally using SLC NAND rather than MLC NAND, which is much more resilient to exhausting the write capacity of the cells and generally will allow an order of magnitude or higher of writes.  It isn't in common usage simply because it's still significantly more expensive.  I would recommend for a workload like this that you buy an SLC drive.